# How to install a different version of Elasticsearch in DDEV

Tags: elasticsearch, ddev

I just installed the elasticsearch (https://github.com/drud/ddev-elasticsearch) add-on on my DDEV site, which is listed on the ddev documents:
https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/additional-services/

The problem is that I need to downgrade the Elasticsearch version to 7.6 and this add-on installed Elasticsearch at version 7.17.6.

I cant not find additional documentation on how to install the specific version of this Elasticsearch add-on, I see that the version is listed in the docker-compose.elasticsearch.yaml file, I tried changing it there, but it complain.

Any tips or reference will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using https://github.com/ddev/ddev-elasticsearch mostly just installs a `docker-compose.elasticsearch.yaml` for you. You can change the version there.

Change `image: elasticsearch:7.17.6` to an appropriate value. `image: elasticsearch:7.6.2`

You have to look at https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/tags to see what tags are available, but it looks like you probably want 7.6.2.

However, if you have Apple Silicon (arm64) architecture, you're mostly going to be limited to the images that are pushed for arm64.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like it can work, but I am running an M1 and while trying this I ran into another issue saying `elasticsearch Pulling no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries`. Now I have to look into this

Comment: If you're running on mac M1, you have to use an image that is arm64. So you have to use a newer image. You can look through the images on https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/tags for one that has arm64. But just use the newer v7 one if you can.